# How to change href address port via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple href but pointing to another port, i.e. one of a set of buttons href address should be substituted and manipulated to point to a valid adress:

```
<div id="btnLSR" class="btn" > <a href="extern.rms:8080"> </a> </div>
```

Should point to 'http://hostname:8080/extern.rms'

I slightly manipulated the javascript from another solution like this

```
<script language="JavaScript">  
  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       var target = event.target;
             if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a')
             {        
                 var port = target.getAttribute('href').match(/:(\d+)$/);    
                 if (port)
                 { 
                     target.port = port[1];
                     window.alert(target.port + " " + target.href);
                     target.href = target.href.replace("/:"+target.port, "");
                 } 
             }
    }, false);

</script>
```

But there is no way to point to the right address. Currently this link is pointing to 'http://extern.rms:8080', i.e. there is no change.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask why you're not just linking to `http://hostname:8080/extern.rms` in the href?

Comment: Sure, because the hostname may change frequently

Comment: Fair point. Take a look at my answer, that might do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var target = event.target;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
        // Split 'extern.rms:8080' up into a array: ['extern.rms','8080'];
        var h = target.getAttribute('href').split(':');
        // Set the href to: The current `origin` + ':' + '8080' + '/' + 'extern.rms';
        target.href = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + ':' + h[1] + '/' + h[0];
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: unfortunately, in my case this resolves to 'http://localhost/undefined8080/extern.rms'

Comment: I forgot to add the `+ ':'`, could you try that?
If that doesn't work, what do your `window.location` and `h` variables contain?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already added the missing ":". The problem is, as you've mentioned the window.location variable. It contains: "undefined". h is (extern.rms,8080).

Comment: Hm, how about the `location` variable? (So, remove `window.` from the code) What browser are you using?
@ndtreviv: `origin` does exist in chrome, I kinda picked the most suitable I saw. `hostname` could be a alternative. (When `'http://'` is added manually, that is)

Comment: I believe window.location.origin is what is undefined. Shouldn't it be window.location.hostname?

Comment: This is true. window.location.hostname works fine. Additionally I added a "http://" as target.href prefix and checked the href for matching a port. Thanks to you all!

Comment: @JohnRumpel: I'll update my answer to reflect that. I'm glad to be of help! Also, please consider marking this as the answer ;-)